# Delphi routine which retrieve the current time and date from a time server

Tags: delphi, timezone, communication, delphi-7

I am looking for a **Delphi 7** routine which connects to a **time server** to retrieve the **correct time and date**, and a routine to update the time and date of the pc.

The routine should of course take into account the time zone the pc is using.

If possible using the **ICS component** suite from [Overbyte](http://www.overbyte.be) (because I use this set of free components for html and ftp access already). But if not, any solution would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is Windows functionality that only needs to be set up. Don't duplicate that in your application.

Comment: Ok, what if I want to set the time on an external device ? The fact remains, that I want to retrieve the correct time and date from a time server. And further: where do you set this in your PC (XP) ? I think you are too quick to downvote a question. It's not because someone else (or even my pc) does it, that a program may not do the same thing.

Comment: Found out where to set the time syncho (but on my pc this gives an error for both the time servers which are present in the list).

Comment: I don't understand the point about external devices. Setting it under XP: "Internet Time" page of the dialog that appears when the clock is double clicked. As for implementing it: This is something that belongs into a service. In a domain you get time synchronization for free. Standard users may not even have permission to adjust the time. (Just to name a few of the issues.)

Comment: I actually think that getting the time from a time server is the easy part of this problem; any time-zone conversion you might have to do is going to require careful thought (although you might just cop-out with that and require that the selected time server is already in your PC's timezone), but most important is @mghie's last point above; actually setting the machine date/time from inside your program. Do you know what environment the program will run in (corporate-network, home-user etc) and the versions of Windows you need to cover? These will have an impact on your solution.

Comment: @robsoft: I thought time servers always returned UTC times, so the conversion is the same regardless of which ones(s) you use.

Comment: @Bruce - heh thanks, you live and learn (he says, having never done anything with a time server!) In that case, his real problems will be figuring out what his time zone is (and thus what the conversion will be) and then seamlessly setting the machine time (which is the bit that I'm actually interested to see any suggestions or solutions for).

Comment: @robsoft: The conversion is pretty straight forward, too.  http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_2704.asp?SK=

Comment: Also, resolution is an issue.  You must take in to consideration lag time between the time server response and receipt of that response by the requesting machine. For most uses, this isn't that critical...but something to be aware of if you need millisecond accuracy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at Indy's IdDayTime component.  Point it to your favourite time server and check the DayTimeStr property.

```
  IdDayTime1.Host := 'time-a.nist.gov';
  Label1.Caption := IdDayTime1.DayTimeStr;
```

**Edit**:
The result is in UTC time, so you'll probably need to [convert it](http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_2704.asp?SK=).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to google for "Delphi 7 NTP" or "Delphi 7 Network Time Protocol". Also, there must be *tons* of free components out there that you can use for free.

Comment: Tried Googling but of course asked the wrong question obviously. Thx.